# How to get array response in swift iOS Request

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, request

I send request like this:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                completion(nil)
                return
            }


            print("********_Respone status code is: ",(response as! HTTPURLResponse).statusCode)
            print("********_Respone url code is: ",response?.url as Any )

            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as! [String: Any]

                let res:HTTPURLResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse

                print(json)// yessssssssss goooood
            } catch {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
}


        task.resume()
```

it's working correctly when response is a Dictionary, but when my response is an array show this error:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayI' to 'NSDictionary'

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deserialize the JSON **once** and omit the options, `Array` and `Dictionary` aren't *fragmented*. Then optional bind the result.

```
do {
     let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
     if let jsonArray = json as? [[String:Any]] {
        print("json is array", jsonArray)
     } else if let jsonDictionary = json as? [String:Any] {
        print("json is dictionary", jsonDictionary)
     } else {
        print("This should never be displayed")
     }
} ...
```

If the result is supposed to be only Array or Dictionary then you can force unwrap the result to dictionary and remove the last `else` clause

```
do {
     let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
     if let jsonArray = json as? [[String:Any]] {
        print("json is array", jsonArray)
     } else {
        let jsonDictionary = json as! [String:Any] 
     }
} ...
```